# Find the average rate of change of $g(t)=t^2+3t+1$ on the interval [0,a]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on a textbook question "Find the average rate of change of $g(t)=t^2+3t+1$ on the interval $[0,a]$". The solution provided, along with the steps in between is:

Avg. rate of change:

= $\frac{g(a)-g(0)}{a-0}$

= $\frac{(a^2+3a+1)-(0^2+3(0)+1)}{a-0}$

= $\frac{a^2+3a+1-1}{a}$ # Here - how did they get rid of -0 in denominator?

= $\frac{a(a+3)}{a}$

= $a+3$

Where I'm stuck is between the second and third step. How does one go from denominator of $a-0$ to just $a$?

Comment: Well, $a-0=a$. Subtracting zero doesn't change the value.

Comment: It follows from the field axioms that $-0=0$ and $a+0=a$.

Comment: let us say that you have the number 7. You can say that $7-0=7$ is that not obvious?

Comment: Similar question: How did they get right of $0$ at the $\textrm{numerator}$? $$1-1=-0=+0$$

Comment: I'm not sure what the expression is for the frame of mind but I think I was looking too hard for a technical approach of some kind without seeing the obvious sitting right in front of me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any number $a, a-0=a$.  Subtracting $0$ makes no change.

Comment: I feel silly now :(
I will take a 5 minute break. Thank you for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 3):

Just as $1-0=1$ or $5-0=5$ we get $a-0=a$

Note that $a$ represent an arbitrary real number so it follows real numbers axioms.